# Should careers.stackoverflow.com support hResume?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, microformats

Jeff recently posted a blog about [hosting CVs on careers.stackoverflow.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001308.html)

I asked in the comments whether there were any plans to support [hResume](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume). Jeff said it was a great idea and that I should post it here on meta.stackoverflow.com to see what interest there might be.

So, question is, "Should careers.stackoverflow.com support the hResume microformat?"

Feel free to vote!

Some background:

[hResume](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume) is a microformat dedicated to the markup of CVs/Resumes to facilitate data exchange. For example:

- The Guardian recently began accepting hResume formatted CVs on their [careers website](http://careers.guardian.co.uk/)
- [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com) exposes using hResume

Comment: Too sad that [hResume support has been dropped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92832/have-hresume-and-microformats-been-dropped) since Careers 2.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I implemented [hResume](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume) for Public CVs. The hResume microformat is layered on existing, older [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) and [hCalendar](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcalendar) microformats.

I used the [Firefox Operator add-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4106), which was [written by this guy](http://www.kaply.com/weblog/operator/), to test and make sure everything was working right.

There's also hCard validators at:
http://ufxtract.com/
http://hcard.geekhood.net/

Implementing this was awkward, because our data is relatively unstructured, and these formats assume you have highly, rigidly structured data. Some of the mappings don't seem quite right to me, but I couldn't figure out any better way. I did browse around some public LinkedIn profiles which are hResume enabled to see how they did it.

Feedback welcome of course!

Comment: Great news Jeff. I'll send this round to the microformats discussion list and try to solicit some feedback.

Comment: Awesome that this is possible, but I'm having trouble finding out how to actually do this export. What am I missing?

Answer (score 32):

Yes Yes YES!

Microformats are the future!

Not only should SOCareers support hResume, but I think that Jeff should look into other microformats (although none are as important as hResume) - [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) for profile pages and [rel="license"](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-license) <strike>and [rel="tag"](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag)</strike> for the SO content pages!

EDIT: Jeff commented that rel="tag" is indeed used on SO pages. +1 for using some microformats on SO!

Comment: we already do "tag" on tags. tsk tsk..

Comment: btw, not a fan of hCard because I think the markup required is sort of idiotic. But I'll look at it again.

Comment: Hm. So you do. Has it always been that way? I remember looking a few months back, and didn't see it.

Comment: Yeah, might as well. I don’t know that microformats are the future particularly, but it might make it easier for some hiring companies to use the data in ways the Stack Overflow team didn’t anticipate.

Comment: "it might make it easier for some hiring companies to use the data in ways the Stack Overflow team didn’t anticipate"

That might be the best justification for microformats I've ever heard. Expose the data - let other people do cool things with it!

I agree that microformats are not the future. They are merely a big part of it :)

Comment: So, maybe they aren't the future...but they sure help with the so-called Web 3.0/Semantic Web. Mark up the data so it all has meanings and let the consumers do...well...whatever they want to do with it.

Comment: No arguments here Thomas. I can't wait until microformats proliferate.

Comment: How come there is not a NO in this poll? :)

Comment: Raj,
You can vote it down if you like. Though please leave a comment saying why you chose to do so.

Regards
Jamie

Comment: I added rel="license" to the two links at the bottom of the footer, will be deployed later

Comment: That might be the worst justification of microformats, I can now automatically spam only those people who have c/c++ in their CV without having to be able to read.

Comment: Too sad that [hResume support has been dropped](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92832/have-hresume-and-microformats-been-dropped) since Careers 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a very sound idea (and fits well with the reverse request to be able to pull in existing resumes (e.g. from LinkedIn) that are marked up as such.

Would also like to see externally linked URLs on career profile pages marked as @rel=me for full semantically linked goodness (I note that the personal URL already has a @rel=nofollow).

Comment: Hmm, you're the admin for http://microformats.org ...+1

Comment: One of a few, but yes - I wasn't intending to come tow a party line - just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

It would also be *totally awesome* if you could point it an existing hResume and have it pre-populate your CV on careers.stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

In general the hCard and hCalendar are working well, but the hResume needs some work.

1- The education and experience are currently mark-up as:

```
<div class="vcard vevent">
```

You need to add the compound class name like so

```
<div class="vcard vevent education">
<div class="vcard vevent experience">
```

2- As you are using linkedin.com pattern combining hCard and hCalendar together for education and experience it’s a good idea mark-up all the data items for both schemas.

```
<div class="statement note">
```

Should also include the description from hCalendar

```
<div class="statement note description">
```

3- You need to mark-up the summary for hResume. Summary is the word use in CV where as the US use the word objectives, means the same thing.

```
<div class="intro-statement statement">
```

Should also include the summary from hResume

```
<div class="intro-statement statement summary">
```

4- Although it not called for in the specification is very useful to mark-up the hCard that carries the main contact information. Some parsers will not find it otherwise

```
<div class="intro-wrapper vcard">
```

Should also include the contact from hResume

```
<div class="intro-wrapper vcard contact">
```

5- The biggest issue is the dtStart and the dtEnd, these should be in the ISO datetime format yyyy-mm-dd etc. Unlike adr there is no label property to display a text formatted version of a date it has to be in a machine readable format

```
<div class="header-time dtstart dtend">April 2006 - May 2008</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="header-time">
    <span class='dtstart'>
        <span class='value-title' title='2006-04'>July 2006</span>
    </span>  -
    <span class='dtend'>
        <span class='value-title' title='2008-05'>May 2008</span>
    </span>  
</div>
```

The convention is that if there is no dtend property for an hCalendar the event is considered ongoing

```
<div class="header-time dtstart dtend">April 2006 - Current</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="header-time">
    <span class='dtstart'>
        <span class='value-title' title='2006-04'>July 2006</span>
    </span> - Current 
</div>
```

If you have date data that already fits the ISO format you can place directly in the text of an element

```
<div class="header-time dtstart dtend"> 2006 - 2008</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="header-time">
    <span class='dtstart'>2006</span> - 
    <span class='dtend'>2008</span>
</div>
```

If you need a parser to try this out against try http://ufxtract.com/
I would be more than happy to help out with the mark-up. I have had a lot of experience both creating and parsing all three of the formats you’re using.

Glenn Jones

PS thanks for taking the time and effort for doing this

Comment: Jeff - I have created a hResume to Word/PDF conversion API if your interested. 

http://lab.madgex.com/hresume/

At the moment it does not work with stackoverflow as you need to fix some of the item above, but work fine then.

Answer (score 2):

If they are marked up with microformats, the data will be available for Enhanced Results via SearchMonkey. If SO marks up with uF and starts showing up prevalantly on yahoo results, I'll make an enhanced result for resumes.

For example, [videos](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=searchmonkey+video) [products](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=ipod+5g+amazon), [reviews](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=thai+chili+santa+clara), [reference](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=stackoverflow+wikipedia).