# API for careers that allows updates

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, api

I'd like to be able to maintain my Stack Overflow Careers resume from an external application, to reduce the amount of effort I have to put into keeping it up to date.

I use [WordPress Resume Manager](http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-resume-manager/) to keep my resume updated, but I imagine there would be other applications that could use such an API, too.

I should also mention that I wrote the above mentioned resume manager, so I can quickly add support into the plugin.

Comment: Why? How is the careers site so difficult to use?

Comment: It's easy to use. I just don't want to spend time maintaining my resume in several different places - it's annoying enough having to update Linkedin.

Comment: @Gary: So just maintain it in the one spot then. This sounds like a problem on your end.

Comment: Maintaining it in one spot is a nice idea, but not really practical. Having a Linkedin profile is expected of everyone in this industry these days. The Linkedin printable version is pretty nasty, so you have to maintain your local copy as well. Want a version on your website? There's a third. Want to use Stack Overflow Careers? Fourth. I want to be able to maintain all of them from one spot, and having an API for Stack Overflow Careers would help that along the way.

Comment: @Gary: Considering it is different information, I don't see this being practical anytime soon.

Comment: Different information? How so? It's all the same information, just in different formats. CVs are hardly the most complex documents. hResume and EuroPass CV formats both document them pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

Careers hResume support has been greatly improved recently.  Not only are public CVs marked-up for easy **export** from Careers, you can also import<sup>1</sup> hResume CVs from arbitrary pages.

Between these two functions you could keep - with a tiny amount of manual labor - a number of different locations for the same CV in sync.  Probably the easiest thing to do would be to make your public Careers CV the canonical one, and drive everything else off of it.

That being said, a fully fledged API for Careers (especially a write-enabled one) isn't in the works as that's an awful lot of work to build something that would only be of utility to a handful of people.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Do note that such a CV will be imported as "drafts."</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If SOC is [made to output hResume](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28375/should-careers-stackoverflow-com-support-hresume), then I don't see why it couldn't be made to *accept* hResume as well... Then, just write a tool to work with that. Or just use SOC as your source, and drive everything else with the hResume export

Comment: That's all I'm asking for. Any method to use software to connect to SOC. hRresume is fine with me.