# Careers Time Frame gives Bad Example

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There is a little problem with the Time Frame Box:
[alt text http://lab.chacha102.com/timeframe.png](http://lab.chacha102.com/timeframe.png)

If you notice, I can't type in one of the examples and have it validate....

This is annoying as I'd like to show the achievements I've accomplished before I graduate.

And as the picture states, about 2 hours ago my team just won a Robotics Rookie All-Star Award, and I came upon this error while trying to insert it into my CV. Yay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of improvements* to our [implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28375/should-careers-stackoverflow-com-support-hresume) of [hResume](http://microformats.org/wiki/hresume) on public CVs, Careers has gotten a lot stricter about what constitutes a "valid" Time Frame.  In the past Time Frame's were basically free-form text entry, which has made moving forward without breaking anything... interesting, let's say.

Anyway, good catch on one of my oversights!  The examples on Careers have been updated to be things you can **actually** enter without error.

<sub>*To the curious amongst you, hResume uses hCalendar to specify education and employment timeframes, and hCalendar requires you format your dates as ISO8601 "datetimes."  This drove the tightening of Career's validation of Time Frames.</sub>