# Have hResume and microformats been dropped?

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, microformats

Has support for hresume and microformats been dropped? I am unable to detect any.

I thought that they were supported - at least on top of hcard and hcalendar - according to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28375/should-careers-stackoverflow-com-support-hresume) and [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/microformats-boon-or-bane.html).

[This](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sandeepan) resume (thanks for letting me use it!) does not find any microformats (hresume, hcalendar, or hcard) using  [this validator](http://ufxtract.com/), [this validator](http://hcard.geekhood.net/), or any [parsers](http://microformats.org/wiki/parsers).

What gives? Can we have our microformats back? (Or do I have to write yet another program screen-scrape and parse through yet another format for data?)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not on Careers right now so I can't tell you about that. Nevertheless, improving your accept rate would help you to get better/faster answers. See the FAQ.

Comment: @M'vy Actually, because of the odd nature of Meta, no one really pays attention to accept rate here.

Comment: @M'vy: What in the world are you talking about? This is Meta. Nobody cares about accept rate here.

Comment: or, you know, what @waiwai993 said ;)

Comment: @balpha Ah ? Didn't know about that. BTW this can't be a bad thing. :D

Comment: @M'vy hahaha, no worries! Hopefully the masses will upvote this feature request enough that the Stackoverlords will take notice in spite of my dismal meta accept rate!

Comment: Would an export to xml be as useful for you?

Comment: @Ian Sure, an export to XML also accomplishes the same task in my view. For me, it is less about *which* standard is used and more about being able to retrieve my data. Doing a save-as of the HTML is kinda like exporting XML, but then I have to try and figure out which DIV identifiers are important (which are subject to change) and makes it harder to use parsers (XML or microformat) that have already been written.

Answer (score 9):

When we redid the profile pages for [Careers 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/careers-2-0-launches/) we decided not to bother with hresume support until someone actually asked for it again.  It has been just a hair over 3 months, and you are the first person to notice (or at least, the first to care enough to bring it to our attention).

So, while we like open standards and hresume in general, there doesn't seem to be enough actual use of this feature to justify bringing it back.

**If this is a feature you would actually use, please vote this question up**.  Also, I'm curious what people use it for, so please leave a comment about that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response! To answer your question: I started to write some code to take my SO resume and propagate it in other formats or to my personal website (with the added bonus of being able to add a useful script to my github repo!) This has been on my list of projects for a while, and today I sat down to write it and found that I couldn't! Like many, I only update (or even think about) my resume once every so often, and I suspect this wouldn't come up until both someone was thinking about resumes and had an hresume itch to scratch. I appreciate your looking at this!

Comment: Also - not to beat a dead horse here - but some of the highest-rated `careers` questions on meta are about exporting the resume! If you had some language-agnostic format (json, xml, microformat) that you exported to, then we (programmers) could take care of schlepping it into PDF or whatever other format we want.

Comment: I was using my CV on careers as an hResume source, and exporting it out to various places.  My blog (wordpress), and downloading on the fly into a PDF and Word Doc using http://lab.madgex.com/hresume/ I didn't realize it wasn't working until recently. I was hoping it would be one of those things that I could "set and forget", but then the format got dropped, and now I am left where I started. hResume would allow me to only have to keep my CV up to date in one place (careers) and output to the rest of the world. Unfortunately without a microformat in place that isn't possible anymore.

Comment: the first person to notice...*note* that microformats are for bots, not people. :)  the entire web noticed microformats, thats why they're the most used semantic technology currently. furthermore...you decided "not to bother with hresume support"...wat? they're html classes...did you disable the class attribute? or just couldn't bear to keep those classes in the markup? i bet you simply replaced the classes. curious, i am. i know this is years old, and there'll be nothing to come of it, but humor me. please. curious, i yam :)